# "Trial and error" method to find a solution and covergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Why is it that a "trial and error" method, choose a value of $x$ and use the right hand side of the equation to find a new value of $x$ and use that new vale of $x$ in the right hand side of the equation etc  . . . . . . ,  to solve for $x$ does not work for an equation of the form $x = -a +b\,e^{-x/c}$, where $a,b$ and $c$ are constants, and yet when rearranged as $x = c\,\ln\left( \dfrac{b} {x+a}\right)$ convergence is very rapid?

Comment: Usually we cannot predict the sign. So in some cases, we will need more than $\ 2\ $ trials to find a suitable interval having to contain a real root.

Comment: Basically, the last line summarizes what I have doing all my life (OK : 62+ years of work).